# Model do Spring 4.3.1

Tags: java, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-data

Não sei trabalhar 100% com #POST e #GET ainda, meu problema deve estar em entender como ocorrem as requisições e quando os meus objetos são instanciados. Seguem métodos:

```
CaixaOperacaoController.java

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/caixa")
public class CaixaOperacaoController {

    @Autowired
    private RepositorioCaixaOperacao repositorioCaixaOperacao;

    @Autowired
    private RepositorioDfeEmitidos repositorioDfeEmitidos;

    @Autowired
    private RepositorioRecibo repositorioRecibo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pesquisa", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String pesquisa() {

        return "caixa.pesquisa.tiles";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listar(Model model) {
        List<CaixaOperacao> caixas = repositorioCaixaOperacao.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("caixas", caixas);
        return "caixa.listar.tiles";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/alterar/{idCaixaOperacao}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String alterar(@PathVariable("idCaixaOperacao") Integer idCaixaOperacao, Model model) {
        Recibo reciboAlt = repositorioRecibo.findByIdCaixaOperacao(idCaixaOperacao);
        CaixaOperacao caixaOperacao = repositorioCaixaOperacao.findByIdCaixaOperacao(idCaixaOperacao);

        DfeEmitido dfeEmitido = new DfeEmitido();

        dfeEmitido.setCaixaOperacao(caixaOperacao);

        model.addAttribute("recibo", reciboAlt);
        model.addAttribute("dfeEmitido", dfeEmitido);

        System.out.println(dfeEmitido.getCaixaOperacao().getIdCaixaOperacao());

        return "caixa.alterar.tiles";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/alterar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String alterar(@ModelAttribute("dfeEmitido") @Valid DfeEmitido dfeEmitido, BindingResult result, Model model) {

        System.out.println(dfeEmitido.getCaixaOperacao());

        repositorioDfeEmitidos.save(dfeEmitido);
        return "redirect:/caixa/pesquisa";

    }

}
```

alterar.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>


<c:url var="actionEmitirDfe" value="/caixa/alterar"></c:url>
<form:form  modelAttribute="recibo" >

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nº Documento Fiscal: </label>
                <form:input path="idCaixaOperacao" cssClass="form-control"
                    disabled="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Valor: </label>
                <form:input path="valor" cssClass="form-control" disabled="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Data da Passagem: </label>
                <form:input path="dataOperacao" cssClass="form-control"
                    disabled="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Forma de Pagamento: </label>
                <form:input path="formaPagamento" cssClass="form-control"
                    disabled="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Categoria do Veículo: </label>
                <form:input path="categoriaVeiculo" cssClass="form-control"
                    disabled="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Arrecadador: </label>
                <form:input path="usuario" cssClass="form-control" disabled="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>

<form:form action="${actionEmitirDfe}" method="post"
    modelAttribute="dfeEmitido">

    <div class="row" hidden="true">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nº Documento Fiscal: </label>
                <form:input path="caixaOperacao.idCaixaOperacao" cssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Placa do Veículo: </label>
                <form:input path="placaVeiculo" cssClass="form-control" />
                <form:errors path="placaVeiculo" cssStyle="color: red"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="EMITIR DFE" class="btn btn-defout">
</form:form>
```

Essa página é resultado de uma outra página chamada pesquisa, onde coloco o `id` de CaixaOperação, resultando nos dados do registro nos campos.

Contudo quando tento salvar `DfeEmitido`, o `IdCaixaOperação` vai nulo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está fazendo uma requisição de `GET` para `/caixa/alterar` e não está passando o valor do id do caixa de operação ao final da URL, portanto você recebe `null`.

Para que fosse possível receber o valor, você precisaria passar na URL a informação. Exemplo, se quisesse passar o valor `123456` como `idCaixaOperacao`:

```
<c:url var="actionEmitirDfe" value="/caixa/alterar/123456"></c:url>
```

Tem algumas coisas estranhas no código também com relação ao bom uso do REST. Normalmente, não se usa `GET` para fazer alterações, usa-se `PUT`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/alterar/{idCaixaOperacao}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
```

Comment: O spring tem o `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` para trabalhar com `PUT`/`DELETE` nestes casos, como tá usando a _tag library_ já tem o _field_.

Comment: @BrunoCésar, obrigado pela correção, já fiz a alteração.